# Create JSON api for product categories

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to creating a web services for product category . I have created the files in etc folder i.e config.xml,api.xml and wsdl.xml .Under model i have created a product folder in it there is a api.php file. can anyone tell how to get the response in json form . i am getting the xml format in response. i want alll the product categories in that.

**Click here to check the demo**

```
dev.webtechstairs.com/ecommerce/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1?products
```